# Maintaining backcolor when mouse click on treeview childs

Tags: asp.net

How to maintain background color when mouse click any one of the children in ASP.NET TreeView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the treenodedatabound event for the tree view and add for each item onclick event to call a javascript function to do whatever you want

```
   protected void TreeView1_TreeNodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {
           e.Node.Text = "<span onclick='javascript:MyFunction(this);'>Text</span>";
        }
```

or you can add the items in this way

```
Dim deletenode As New TreeNode("<span onclick=""javascript:confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this ?');"">Delete</span>", "0" & dr("ProjectID"))
```

Js function sample

```
MyFunction(sender) { 
//using jquery you have the html element (td ) you can get any value from that element based on your senario 
//for example you have attribute called x holding the value you want 
alert( $(sender).attr("x")); 

//or to change the background color 
$(sender).css("background-color" , "blue"); 

}
```

Comment: can u provide 'javascript:MyFunction(this); function?

Comment: function MyFunction(sender)
{
    //usiing jquery you have the html element (td ) you can get any value from that element based on your senario 
//for example you have attribute called x holding the value you want 
  alert(  $(sender).attr("x"));
  //or to change the background color 
  $(sender).css("background-color" , "blue");
}

Comment: i am not sure of the syntax  
sender.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

Comment: Hi Mr.Titan Im prohibited to use jquery ..can u pls provide in javascript